# downloading a file from one EC2 instance to another EC2 instance during vagrant multi-VM provisioning

Tags: amazon-ec2, vagrant, chef-infra, scp

My application consists of two components: server and agent. 
I am using Vagrant to create two EC2 instances. One for each application component.
First, I create the server instance and provision it with Chef.
Now, I am trying to provision the agent instance. To do so, I need to download the agent deployment package from the server instance to the agent instance.

The best way is to use scp with the server instance private ip. 
How can I share the server private ip address with the agent provision process (Chef)?

Comment: Do you use a chef-server ? if yes it's IP (internal and external) should be populated in node attributes, so you should be able to access them from agent (via a search with a tag or a specific role for example).

Comment: No. I use chef-zero for now. I would defently check the posibility to work with chef server

Comment: Youay consider switching to chef-zero to save node states on a shared place (filesystem) and take advantage of the search feature. Other options coming to my mind are chef-server, hashicoorp consul and zookeeper. Any central place to store states/service availability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the vagrant host manager plugin (https://github.com/smdahlen/vagrant-hostmanager) could help.

*From the documentation*

> You can customize way, how host manager resolves IP address for each
>   machine. This might be handy in case of aws provider, where host name
>   is stored in ssh_info hash of each machine. This causes generation of
>   invalid /etc/hosts file.
>
> Custom IP resolver gives you oportunity to calculate IP address for
>   each machine by yourself, giving You also access to the machine that
>   is updating /etc/hosts. For example:
>
> ```
> config.hostmanager.ip_resolver = proc do |vm, resolving_vm|
>   if hostname = (vm.ssh_info && vm.ssh_info[:host])
>     `host #{hostname}`.split("\n").last[/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/, 1]
>   end
> end
> ```

Comment: Thanks @Frederic. I am trying to figure out how to implement it. Please do provide a code snippet of the Vagrantfile if you know.